# Python, what to use instead of itterrows in this case?

Tags: python, pandas

im trying to speed up my program, im fairly new to python and pandas and i just used this code to see if it worked and it does, however is there a way to speed it up. I know itterrows is very slow and maybe the .apply function is faster but i have no clue how to use it when i want to use the current row position in it. Maybe one of u can help me out.

Here is my code:

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if df.iloc[i, 2] == 1000:
        list = []
        datum = df.iloc[i, 0]
        id = df.iloc[i, 1]
        for j, row in df.iterrows():
            if df.iloc[j, 0] == datum:
                if df.iloc[j, 0] != id:
                    waarde = df.iloc[j, 2]
                    if waarde != 1000:
                        waarde2 = df.iloc[j-1, 2]
                        respectivelijk = waarde / waarde2
                        # print(waarde)
                        # print(waarde2)
                        # print(respectivelijk)
                        list.append(respectivelijk)
        # print(list)
        gem = sum(list) / len(list)
        # print(gem)
        # print(df.iloc[i-1, 2])
        correcte_waarde = (gem * df.iloc[i-1, 2])
        # print(correcte_waarde)
        df.set_value(i, 'water_level', correcte_waarde)
```

My dataframe looks like this:
https://gyazo.com/0fdce9cbac81562195e4f24d55eac9a9
I am using this code to replace the errors(value 1000) with a value based on the changes in value of the other objects. For example if all other objects rise 50% in the hour missing i can presume/estimate the missing value will rise 50% aswell.

Comment: You should post an excerpt from your file (and include it in the question as text) and the desired transformed dataset. This will not only help us answering but it will make the question potentially useful for future readers (see also [mcve]).

Comment: Forgive me if I've misunderstood your code, but if you're simply finding values equalling 1000 and replacing them with the values from the previous row, you could replace your values == 1000 with NaNs, and use some sort of filling to replace the NaNs (either `fillna()` or `interpolate()`). E.g.: `df["Value"].replace(1000, np.NaN, inplace=True); df["Value"].interpolate(method="values", inplace=True)`

Comment: I am finding values with 1000, however im not replacing them with the last found value of that rows object_id. Im using the other object_id's to fill in the gap by looking how much they have risen/dropped in %.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot tell from your explanation what exactly you want to achieve. I assume that

- 1) you want to find all rows where the value of `Value` (you must use another name here...) is `equal to 1000`, because it represents an error reading.
- 2) that you then want to replace the `1000` with something more representative, for example, by using interpolation.

I will work from those two assumptions. I use the `temp` column to represent your `value` column.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# seed for reproducibility
np.random.seed(seed=1111)

# generate a dataframe with random datetimes and values
date_today = datetime.now()
days = pd.date_range(date_today, date_today + timedelta(1000), freq='D')
data = np.random.randint(1, high=100, size=len(days))
df = pd.DataFrame({'the_date': days, 'temp': data})
df = df.set_index('the_date')

print(df)

# get all the indicies of the temp column where the value equals 23. Change it to 1000 for your data.
select_indices = list(np.where(df["temp"] == 23)[0])

# replace all values in the temp column that equal 23 with NAN. Change 23 to 1000 for your data.
df.loc[df['temp'] == 23] = np.nan

# interpolate the data and replace the NAN's
interpolated_df = df.interpolate(method='linear', axis=0).ffill().bfill()

# get the interpolated rows, just to see what values the NAN's were replaced with
interpolated_rows = interpolated_df.iloc[select_indices]

print(interpolated_rows)
```

Hopefully this helps.